# Trying to generate random numbers in a dice game in solidity with chainlink?

Tags: solidity, randomness

[image]
I am trying to learn solidity by doing a dice game, I found code online that I would like to start with however I am stuck with trying to get the definition of _vrfConsumerBase and _link. I am aware this code might be made with old chainlink code however I can't find any better sources.

Comment: Hi OliverPaine! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! To get better help can you provide the contract as text? a link to a repository is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

well you have to put the values of the links and vrf, you can find the addresses here based on the network you are using:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/

Remember to fund your contract with links before running it

Comment: shoud've specified I did this like this: _vrfCoordinator = 0x3d2341ADb2D31f1c5530cDC622016af293177AE0;
    _link = 0xb0897686c545045aFc77CF20eC7A532E3120E0F1;

but returned parser error expected identifier but got "="